# conditional compiling three-file project

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have three files:
main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file3.h"
#define PERMISSION

int main()
{
  #ifdef PERMISSION
  myfunction1();
  #else
  myfunction2();
  #endif // PERMISSION
return 0;
}
```

file2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file3.h"

#ifdef PERMISSION
void myfunction1()
{
    printf("Inside myfunction1 on file2.c \n");
}
#else
void myfunction2()
{
    printf("Inside myfunction2 on file2.c \n");
}
#endif
```

file3.h

```
#ifndef FILE3_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE3_H_INCLUDED


#ifdef PERMISSION
void myfunction1();
#else
void myfunction2();

#endif
#endif
```

I want to control the compilation of the 3-file project with the macro PERMISSION from the main or from the header file. If it is defined I should get all the myfunction1 parts compiled on all three files. If it is not, the myfunction2 parts. But I am getting an error when  ''#define PERMISSION''  is present wether I place it on main.c or on file3.h

Codeblocks shows me that file2 and file3 are defaulting to the else part, so they are not seeing PERMISSION defined. I don't want to put it on all files and modifify all of them when I want it not defined
Right now it's erroing with undefined reference to myfunction1
Maybe I shouldn't put the #ifdef in the header file file3.h but it doesn't work anyway.

How do I get it right?

Comment: defining it in file3.h makes the most sense since file2.c and main.c both include it

Comment: you're also missing a final `#endif` in file3.h to close out the `#include` guards. That could be manifesting into your problem

Comment: thanks, that was a copy/paste error

Comment: ahh, typo. In file3.h you've got `#ifdef PERMISION` .. you're missing an S.`#define PERMISSION` in file3.h will work after that fix.

Comment: I am sorry, I was editing that after pasting. I have it misspelled but conforming on the IDE

Comment: hmmm, wonder what else is different between your code and what you've posted ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Looks like the suggestion of placing it on file3.h did it, But I remember reading that header files are not supposed to be compiled, so I don't know why it is working

Comment: I first tried without a header file, but it didn't work. I wonder why the other file couldn't see the definition on the first one. Do macros have local scope?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215132/discussion-between-yano-and-juan-carlos-vega-oliver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to #define PERMISSION in all files. Either

- explixitly place is in each file

  put it in a common header

  pass it in the compiler -DPERMISSIONS (if you compiler allow s it)

Comment: If I explicitly put it in each file do I have to include guards for it on each file?. I thought  that by defining it in any of them, it would be visible for all of them, why can't they see it?

Comment: #defines are very primitve, the text of the file is modified. No you dont need a gaurd

Answer (score 0):

add it to your compiler command line there is its place

```
 > I am using Codeblocks. I haven't been able to find the way to pass compiling options to it like in the command line – juan carlos vega oliver 3 hours ago
```

Try under Project -> Build options,  inside tab Compiler settings select tab #defines

Comment: I am using Codeblocks. I haven't been able to find the way to pass compiling options to it like in the command line